# Do not Acces $_SERVER array directly

Tags: php, сервер

Netbeans выдал ошибку что не может получить доступ к переменной, захожу на оф сайт php, там пишет что массив $_SERVER был удален, что делать ?
как заменить?

Нужно узнать строку запроса, наподобие 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: удалено $HTTP_SERVER_VARS , а не $_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю почему но Netbeans Ругался, поэтому нашел аналог кому нужно.

$_request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);